# Custom post type URL with post ID that allows archiving and paging

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I'm having a difficult time trying to get my custom post types URLs to work correctly. Every solution I find has crippled another part that needs to work. What I am trying to accomplish is `domain.com/post_type/post_id/post_name`.

What I have that works for everything except archives is:

```
register_post_type('post-type',
    array(
    'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'post-type/%post_id%',
    'with_front' => false,
    'pages' => true,
    'ep_mask' => 1 
    )
))
```

Then I have:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_type_link', 1, 3);
function custom_post_type_link($post_link, $post = 0, $leavename = false) {

    if ($post->post_type == 'post-type')) {
        return str_replace('%post_id%', $post->ID, $post_link);
    } else {
        return $post_link;
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to find a way to get `domain.com/post_type` to work. It currently throws a 404.

I know that if I remove the filter and `/%post_id%` from my rewrite that the archive will work. From there I've tried adding a rewrite rule:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrites_init' );
function custom_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'post-type/([0-9]+)?$',
        'index.php?post_type=post-type&p=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

Doing it this way the URL wont redirect if someone types in `domain.com/post_type/post_id` and `domain.com/post_type/post_id/post_name/2` doesn't work.

Anyone know of the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code/solutions is pretty good. You use `slug` param in a very smart way, so WordPress automatically creates correct `permastruct` for this CPT.

The only thing you're missing, I guess, is `has_archive` param. It's default value is `false` and you don't set it to true. So WordPress doesn't create archive links/pages for your CPT.

> has_archive (boolean or string)
>
> (optional) Enables post type archives.
>
> Will use $post_type as archive slug by default. Default: false Note:
>   Will generate the proper rewrite rules if rewrite is enabled. Also use
>   rewrite to change the slug used.

If you do this, WordPress will create rewrite rules for archive pages. There will be a tiny problem. They will contain `%post_id%` in them. But it's pretty easy to correct. You just have to add this code after your `register_post_type` call:

```
global $wp_rewrite;

$new_rules = array();
foreach ( $wp_rewrite->extra_rules_top as $key => $rule ) {
    echo $key;
    if (strpos($key, 'post-type/%post_id%/') === 0 ) {
        $new_rules[ str_replace('%post_id%/', '', $key) ] = $rule;
        unset( $wp_rewrite->extra_rules_top[$key] );
    }
}
$wp_rewrite->extra_rules_top = $wp_rewrite->extra_rules_top + $new_rules;
```

It will repair rules for archive pages created by WordPress. It's clean solution - it doesn't leave any mess behind, and it takes care of all rules for archive page (feeds, etc.)

Comment: Just adding `has_archive => true` won't solve the problem, but in addition with birgire's code it will work.

Comment: I played a little bit with this, and updated my answer. The problem was that WordPress created rewrite rules with %post_id% for archive pages. All you have to do is to repair them.

Comment: Thanks @KrzysiekDróżdż, this worked exactly how I wanted it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to add this code snippet:

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_rewrite_rules_array' );
function custom_rewrite_rules_array( $rules ) {
        $newrules = array();
        $newrules['^post-type/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=post-type&paged=$matches[1]';
        $newrules['^post-type$'] = 'index.php?post_type=post-type';
       return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

to add support for `domain.com/post-type/` and `domain.com/post-type/page/2`.

You just have to remember to save the permalinks.

Comment: Well, it's not perfect ;) 1. You leave incorrect rewrite rules created by WP. 2. You don't take care of other rewrite rules that WP creates for archive pages: feeds (not always), and so on.

Comment: well let me post the whole working solution that I tested the above snippet on  ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you get only these rules? You have `has_archive` set to true, but there are no archive rules in your output. It's a little bit strange - WordPress generates them for me (don't forget about extra_rules_top).

Comment: ok maybe I will test it again when I have time, will remove it untill then, thanks for the suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you reset your permalink settings after saving the template file? Before you can use a new permalink like that you must resave your permalink settings in Settings->Permalinks.

Comment: Yes, I do that every time I make a change to the permalinks.

Comment: Well, to be precise you should flush rewrite rules, you don't have to resave permalink settings (you can achieve it in other/more correct ways too).